# Highchart shows text in center on legend mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/fw71sxx6/2/). What I want to do is that when mouseover on legend, text should appear in the center of the donut.

Like it happens when mouseOver at the single piece of the donut.

```
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'distrubution_of_funds',
            type: 'pie',
            borderRadius: 0
        },
```

...

```
        series: [ {
            name: 'Versions',
            data: [{
                "name": "№ 123 (manager)",
                "y":2709.74,
                "color": "#E85620"
            },{
                "name": "№ 333",
                "y":885.5,
                "color": "#92B145"
            }, {
                "name": "other (127)",
                "y": 3151.3274920329,
                "isOther": true,
                "color": "#B6B9BE"
            }],
            size: '80%',
            innerSize: '60%',
            showInLegend: true,
           dataLabels: {
                enabled: false

            }
        }],

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            layout: 'vertical',
            useHTML: true,
            width: 160,

        }

    },
    function(chart) { 

        var xpos = '50%';
        var ypos = '53%';
        var circleradius = 102;

        // Render the text
        chart.innerText = chart.renderer.text('$$$',  270, 210).css({

            color: '#0f1122',
            fontSize: '16px',
            textAlign: 'center'
        }).attr({zIndex: 999}).add();
    });
```

How to do it?

for example working chart [at this page](https://alpari.com/en/investor/pamm/346370/#pamm-equity)

Comment: A little bit tricky, but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/fw71sxx6/4/

Comment: uh, nice. But how to set what data i want. I need just (this.y)?

Comment: You mean this(if this is what you want I can post it as an aswer): http://jsfiddle.net/fw71sxx6/6/

Comment: @Hackerman exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the `jquery` library in order to use less code, so this is not a `vanilla javascript` solution. I added the following code inside of your `function(chart) { // on complete` section:

```
 $(chart.series[0].data).each(function(i, serie){
      $(serie.legendItem.element).hover(function(){
          chart.innerText.attr({text: serie.y})
      }, function(){
          chart.innerText.attr({text: '$$$'});
      });                
 });
```

It's a little bit tricky, but basically, you are attaching a `hover` event on every `legendItem` element, that changes the chart `innerText` attribute, to the `y` property of the `serie`.

**You can see it working here:**  <kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fw71sxx6/6/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Its works here :

http://jsfiddle.net/fw71sxx6/5/

I add jquery for add this in function chart :

```
// Render the text
            chart.innerText = chart.renderer.text('$$$',  270, 210).css({

                color: '#0f1122',
                fontSize: '16px',
                textAlign: 'center',
                display: 'none'
            }).attr({
                class:'getlegend',
                zIndex: 999
            }).add();
```

And I add this script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.highcharts-series').mouseover(function() {
       $('.showlegend').html($('.getlegend').html());
  });
});
```